# express+sequelize+mysql how can i create database dynamically with async before start server

Tags: express, sequelize.js

i have been using express + sequelize + mysql

in many docs, they set database in advanced  before connected sequelize ( start server )

but i don't want to do this
i need to create database dynamically when server started,
and now i got some code from google

actually , it doesn't work in my intension

when i start server, it must failed that they cannot find database
and Second, it will work fine

of course i know this occured by async problem but i don't know how to write it

## models/index.js

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const mysql = require("mysql2/promise");

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
const config = require("../config/config")[env];
const db = {};

mysql
  .createConnection({
    user: config.username,
    password: config.password,
  })
  .then((connection) => {
    connection.query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS template;").then(() => {
      // Safe to use sequelize now
    });
  });

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config.database,
  config.username,
  config.password,
  config
);

Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
  db[modelName].init(sequelize);
});

Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

## app.js

```
const db = require("./models");


...

const app = express();
// mysql
db.sequelize
  .sync()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("db connection ");
  })
  .catch(console.error);

app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 8888);
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

...
```

in this situtation, how can i fix this code ?

im sorry about not good at english ;0;

i tried to move sequelize config in connection.query callback .. i know it is foolish

Comment: what issue in this code?

Comment: at first, database are created and sequelize connection are fail what they cannot find "template" database
and then i quite server and restarted , code is running successfuly 

um.. i want to running concurrently

Comment: Why don't you place creating Sequelize instance and models initialization right in the block where you have the comment `Safe to use sequelize now`?

Comment: @Anatoly i have tried to it, but when set code in that block .
`sync()` cannot founded in `db.sequelize` in `app.js `

Comment: @Anatoly maybe it caused by promisified  
so i changed code like 

`db.then((res) => {
  res.sequelize
    .sync()
    .then(() => {
      console.log("db connection");
    })
    .catch(console.error);
});`
Even if it's properly  converted the promisify code working I could not use Model Object in other routes

Comment: Can you update the post with the most recent version of code?

Comment: @Anatoly im very glad what you try to help me, however i just gave up my atteption . 
i set my mind to set database before start my server app not in code, it would be better for my mentality ...